# Prevent Image blocking while sending emails using php

Tags: php, phpmailer

I tried this code. But image is not shown in the email. I need to display image without getting blocked.

```
require("class.phpmailer.php")
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'username';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->From="ex@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName="Email Image";
$mail->Sender="eg@gmail.com";
$mail->AddReplyTo("xe@gmail.com", "Reply");
$mail->AddAddress("exe@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/D7vQqu3U7j2qWYtvzCLHodLRvMHt1Fq0F5s12lEp2YQc-RPwytgpqhRLhqzIZglky59F4-A-OtVXlmglO2CoS7CrkZk=s0-d-e1-ft#http://litebreeze.com/images/profile_small.jpg',profile_pic,'profile_small.jpg', "base64", "application/octet-stream");
$mail->Body = "This is a test picture: <img src=\"cid:profile_pic\" /></p>";
$mail->AltBody="This is text only alternative body.";
if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "Letter is sent";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing several things wrong here.

- `addEmbeddedImage` expects you to provide a local path to a file, not
  a remote URL.
- You are deliberately setting an incorrect MIME type
- You have not quoted your cid.
- I see no good reason to pull the image from google's proxy cache - just pull it directly from the source.

Fixes for all these:

```
$mail->AddStringEmbeddedImage(file_get_contents('http://litebreeze.com/images/profile_small.jpg'),'profile_pic','profile_small.jpg');
```

You're not using encryption - set `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` and `$mail->Port = 587;`.

You're also using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an obsolete example. Go [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Embedding image works fine now. But the images are not shown in the email by default. Images will get displayed only after "Show images" is clicked. Is there a way to make the images get displayed by default without asking for users permission.

Comment: No, it's under the user's control. That's why it asks. It will probably show the image if the user adds you to their address book.